# Publish ESRI .mxd to leaflet app

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geojson, esri

Is there workflow out there to take an ESRI `.MDX` file that you would usually publish to a web service using `ArcGIS` for Server and instead turn it into GEOJSON or JSON etc. and easily update a leaflet app. From what I'm seeing you would need to update your leaflet app script each time you add a new geo JSON layer.

Please point me in the right direction or let me know if this won't work at all.

Comment: Why don't you publish map services (WMS, TMS, WFS, vector tiles) and consume those with Leaflet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [esri-leaflet plugin](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet) to consume services from ArcGIS for Server.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that people have already offered you an elegant solution by using ESRI-Leaflet plugin.

Another option is to get your shapefiles out of the `.MDX` and use [Ogr2Ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) app to convert ESRI shapefiles into `GEOJSON` or `JSON` format. Then you can simply add those `JSON` layers on your map using Leaflet API. Or you can use jQuery and write a single function that will allow your users to add any number of layers they want to the map dynamically, so they wouldn't even need to reload the page.